# Eloquent updateOrCreate always create

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use updateOrCreate to simplify my code, but the function ALWAYS create a new row, never update.

My migration:

```
        Schema::create('logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->bigIncrements('id');
         $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
         $table->datetime('is_fixed')->nullable();
         $table->datetime('snooze_until')->nullable();
         $table->integer('snooze_while')->nullable();
         $table->string('title', 100);
         $table->string('level', 100);
         $table->string('description');
         $table->string('stage',100);
         $table->json('details')->nullable();
         $table->timestamps();

         $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');
        });
```

My $fillables

```
protected $fillable = [
    'project_id', 
    'is_fixed', 
    'snooze_until', 
    'snooze_while', 
    'title', 
    'level', 
    'description', 
    'stage',
    'details'
];
```

My test

```
    $log = new Log();

    $log->fill([
        'title' => 'Vicente\\Sally\\Schiller',
        'level' => 'ERROR',
        'description' => 'Laboriosam et architecto voluptatem.',
        'stage' => 'production@wender-fedora',
        'details' => '{"app":"MyApp"}',
        'project_id' => 5
    ]);

    Log::updateOrCreate($log->toArray());
```

I have some nullable fields, but I figure this is not a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

updateOrCreate method takes two array params:

- First one is an array of fields =>values that will be used as a condition to check if the row exists or not.
- The second one is an array of fields => values to be updated (in case of a record was matched with the conditions from the first param) or to be added (merged with the first param in case of no match found).

So I guess [Jesus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55839746/10974673) might be the right one for you.

Answer (score 3):

You want to try this one:

```
    Log::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'title' => 'Vicente\\Sally\\Schiller',
            'project_id' => 5
        ], 
        [
            'title' => 'Vicente\\Sally\\Schiller',
            'level' => 'ERROR',
            'description' => 'Laboriosam et architecto voluptatem.',
            'stage' => 'production@wender-fedora',
            'details' => '{"app":"MyApp"}',
            'project_id' => 5
        ]
    );
```